# How can I change the user agent string sent by Chrome on my Nexus 7?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-7, chrome-for-android

Reading the reviews of the [BBC Media Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.uk.co.bbc.android.mediaplayer) on Google Play, [one user](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.uk.co.bbc.android.mediaplayer&reviewId=07654487433814668942) said that since Chrome supports HTML5, he had managed to persuade the BBC iPlayer website to play him streams meant for iPad/iPhone devices by spoofing an IOS user agent string on his Nexus 7.

How might I go about getting the same thing to work myself?

I have looked at [How can I change the user agent for the stock browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6233/4229) and [Method to change browser User Agent based on site](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26055/4229) but both seem to concentrate on the Dolphin browser. Also, please mention if a solution will require me to root my Nexus-7.

Incidentally, I also tried using [Phoney](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/addon/phony/) with Firefox, but although Firefox supports HTML5 and the iPlayer website shows pages without either *install flash* or *use external app* messages, it still won't play the streams (it just sits swirling its progress wheel), hence looking for a solution for Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find any way to do this except by connecting your phone to your computer and using remote web debugging feature to change user agent string.

1. Use this documentation to enable and start using Remote Debugging: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging
2. Open any web page in your Chrome for Android
3. Navigate to localhost:9222 in Chrome browser on your computer and choose tab from your list of tabs opened in your Chrome for Android. You will see developer tools screen.
4. Go to developer tools settings on your computer by clicking on settings icon in bottom left corner of developer tools and change user agent string there
5. Reload web-page in your Android phone

Of course, user agent will fall back to default after you disconect your phone from computer.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly a solution, but, have you tried using Firefox?, you can change the agent string on that browser.

Comment: I tried using [Phoney](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/addon/phony/) with Firefox, but although the iPlayer website shows pages without either *install flash* or *use external app* messages, it still won't play the streams, hence looking for a solution for Chrome.